# AWS trusted advisory report from multiple accounts into a central account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Has anyone implemented logging of Trusted advisory report from multiple accounts into a central account by using lambdas and cloudwatch dashboards etc. If so, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am slightly involved with a project that concentrates on a similar thing. I am assuming that you have a single organisation account and then multiple child accounts and you just want to aggregate all the findings in a single org account. 
I wouldn't advise on waiting with the implementation as AWS is already working on the feature that you just described.

In terms of the lambdas/cloudwatch solution I didn't manage to find anything useful that would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did reach out to AWS as well and they are working on this feature too.